# Itextsharp "token type not recognized"

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, tiff

I am producing a pdf from tiff file. With Acrobat 7 I got the error on opening that a token type is not recognized.
I only see some words from the fulltext but not the pictures in this pdf!

With the acrobat reader X I see the pdf correctly. when I scroll down I got a message that there is an error in this file, but no more information.

Anyone know where the Problem is? I have tried many PDF Versions within Itext without an other result!

Here is some Code:

```
        Clock.hocr.Elements.hDocument hdoc = new Clock.hocr.Elements.hDocument();
        hdoc.AddFile("out3.html");
        Clock.hocr.PDFSettings pdfset = new Clock.hocr.PDFSettings();
        pdfset.ImageType = Clock.hocr.PdfImageType.JPeg;
        pdfset.ImageQuality = 50;
        //pdfset.Subject = "Fulltext";
        //pdfset.Title = "ft";
        //pdfset.Language = "german";
        //pdfset.Author = "datapool";
        pdfset.Dpi=300;
        //pdfset.Keywords="...";
        //pdfset.PdfOcrMode =Clock.hocr.OcrMode.Tesseract;
        pdfset.WriteTextMode = Clock.hocr.WriteTextMode.Word;

        //pdfset.Dpi = 300;

        Clock.hocr.PdfCreator pdfcreat = new Clock.hocr.PdfCreator(pdfset,"test.pdf");
        List<Image> pages = GetAllPages("test.tif");



        for (int i = 0; i<hdoc.Pages.Count;i++)
        {
            Clock.hocr.Elements.hPage hpage = hdoc.Pages[i];
            pdfcreat.AddPage(hpage, pages[i]);


        }


        pdfcreat.SaveAndClose();
```

The Clock.hocr modules you can find on: http://hocrtopdf.codeplex.com/

```
public void AddPage(hPage page, System.Drawing.Image pageImage)
    {
        doc.NewPage();
        doc.AddHeader("COPYRIGHT", "DATAPOOL GmbH");
        AddImage(pageImage);
        WriteUnderlayContent(page);

    }
```

doc is from type itextsharp.text.document

```
public void AddImage(System.Drawing.Image image)
    {
        try
        {
            if (OnProcessImage != null)
            {
                AddImage(OnProcessImage(image));
                return;
            }

            iTextSharp.text.Image i = GetImageForPDF(ImageProcessor.GetAsBitmap(image));

            i.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            // doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(i.Width, i.Height));
            i.ScaleAbsolute(doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.Height);
            doc.Add(i);

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(x.Message);
            throw x;
        }
    }
```

...

```
    private void WriteUnderlayContent(hPage page)
    {
        string pageText = page.Text;
        foreach (hParagraph para in page.Paragraphs)
        {
            foreach (hLine line in para.Lines)
            {
                if (pdfSettings.WriteTextMode == WriteTextMode.Word)
                {
                    line.AlignTops();
                    foreach (hWord c in line.Words)
                    {
                        c.CleanText();
                        BBox b = BBox.ConvertBBoxToPoints(c.BBox, pdfSettings.Dpi);
                        BBox lineBox = BBox.ConvertBBoxToPoints(line.BBox, pdfSettings.Dpi);
                        PdfContentByte cb = cb = writer.DirectContentUnder;

                        BaseFont base_font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, false);
                        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(base_font);

                        float h = (int)Math.Ceiling(b.Height);
                        int font_size = (int)Math.Ceiling(h);
                        if (font_size == 0)
                            font_size = 2;

                        cb.BeginText();
                        cb.SetFontAndSize(base_font, (float)font_size);
                        cb.SetTextMatrix(b.Left, doc.PageSize.Height - b.Top - b.Height);
                        //float spacing = (c.BBox.Width / (c.Text.ToCharArray().Count())) / 100;
                        float spacing = (c.BBox.Width / (c.Text.ToCharArray().Count())) / 100 ;
                        cb.SetCharacterSpacing(spacing);
                        cb.ShowText(c.Text + " ");
                        cb.EndText();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    line.CleanText();
                    BBox b = BBox.ConvertBBoxToPoints(line.BBox, pdfSettings.Dpi);
                    BBox lineBox = BBox.ConvertBBoxToPoints(line.BBox, pdfSettings.Dpi);
                    PdfContentByte cb = cb = writer.DirectContentUnder;

                    BaseFont base_font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, false);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(base_font);

                    float h = (int)Math.Ceiling(b.Height);
                    int font_size = (int)Math.Ceiling(h);
                    if (font_size == 0)
                        font_size = 2;

                    cb.BeginText();
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(base_font, (float)font_size);
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(b.Left, doc.PageSize.Height - b.Top - b.Height);
                    float spacing = (line.BBox.Width / (line.Text.ToCharArray().Count())) / 100;
                    cb.SetCharacterSpacing(spacing);
                    cb.ShowText(line.Text);
                    cb.EndText();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are many different TIFFs in the wild that don't comply with the TIFF standard. That could be one reason. Another reason could be in the way you add the TIFF to the PDF using iTextSharp. Maybe you're doing something wrong. In any case, as you don't share the TIFF, the PDF, nor any of your code, it's very unlikely that somebody will answer your question. This is a typical "it doesn't work" remark without any information that makes it a real question.

Comment: Hello, I have converted the tiff to jpg pages and added as jpeg to the pdf... with the same problem! I think the tiff is not the problem! I cant share this tiff, beacause it is a bill!

Comment: OK, in that case, you're doing something wrong with iText because we can create PDFs containing JPEGs without any problem. When I asked for a code sample, I was expecting to see some real iText code. Instead you're referring to a third party project that is unknown to us. Please contact support of hOcr2Pdf.NET first.

Comment: Please provide a PDF exposing that problem, maybe it is possible to see what goes wrong there.

Comment: an example pdf with tif and hocr is there: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7420065/out2.zip.html

Comment: Please distill your code down to something that we can help you debug. You should be able to add an image to a new PDF in about a dozen or so lines of code. If that's broken, post what you tried. If that works, start adding back your other logic bit by bit until works or breaks.

Comment: I figured out that the error comes from the WriteUnderlayContent function I have posted above. somewhere in the else. Maybe the textlayer must be cleaned or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem! the error was in the wrong CharacterSpacing...
fixed it to -0.0025 and the pdf is working!